# laravel/php response different json data with extra double quotes in different environments

Tags: php, json, laravel

in my mac

```
$result = DB::select("select count(*) as count from table where id=1");
return Response::json($result[0]->count);
```

I got 0 in js

```
// PHP 5.4.24  
0
```

but when I published my codes into Centos, I got "0" even ""0"" in js

```
// PHP 5.5.14
"0" //(sometimes ""0"")
```

They are totally same codes. What's wrong?

---

**Edit:**

I found another problem I think it's related

```
// mac, PHP 5.4.24, Lavavel 4.2
Auth::user()->is_admin === 1  // true

// centos, PHP 5.5.14, Lavavel 4.2
Auth::user()->is_admin === 1  // false
Auth::user()->is_admin == 1  // true
```

column type of is_admin is int(11)

Comment: Is the PHP version same?

Comment: Man, you SHOULD use the Eloquent ORM included in Laravel for Database queries, and it's really hard to know from a different environment I would suggest trying few things, get the result in a key-value php array and then return the json response, or perhaps echoing the resulted value for the $result variable and figuring out it's type.. A matter of trial and error I would say..

Comment: Hi guys, I found another problem. I've edited my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. Because I used php-mysql but not php-mysqlnd. php-mysqlnd returns native data type from mysql, but php-mysql returns some data types like int/float as string.

so I

```
`yum remove php-mysql'
```

then

```
'yum install php-mysqlnd'
```

everything goes fine!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to perform a numeric check when returning the JSON to have the expected type.

```
return Response::json($result[0]->count, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Hi, I found another problem. I've edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: I had the exact problem, but this did not help, this only removes the double quotes on numeric types. Strings still have double-double quotes.